# Replace excisting column in line in file by using PHP

Tags: php, html, passwords, submit

I got a script which I want to modify by using a html/php website.

I want to replace the input which I get from the script file with new variables that I input through the HTML/PHP site. It would be more awesome if someone could give me an example how to do so by typing the right password too, but its not actually a must at the moment.

To be more specific. I want to replace the specific line and specific column which is represented in the in the input boxes. These boxes will always contain the last known configuration. And if I type in new values and save them, these will overwrite the last values at the same line and column which the box represent.

Any help would be welcome.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Rate Limiter</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Change configurations:</h2>

    <form>
    <?php$arscript = file ("C:\dat300backups\script.txt");?>
    IP Subnet: <input type="text" name="ipsubnet" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[13],9,15); ?>"><br>
    IP From: <input type="text" name="ipfrom" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[14],7,3); ?>"><br>
    IP To: <input type="text" name="ipto"  value="<?php echo substr($arscript[15],5,3); ?>"><br>
    WAN: <input type="text" name="wan" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[16],4,4); ?>"><br>
    LAN: <input type="text" name="lan" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[19],4,4); ?>"><br>
    Traffic Control Path: <input type="tcpath" name="tcpath" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[17],3,13); ?>"><br>
    ByteLimit: <input type="text" name="bytelimit" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[18],10,5); ?>"><br>
    Download Rate: <input type="text" name="drate" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[20],6,8); ?>"> kbit/s<br>
    Upload Rate: <input type="text" name="urate" value="<?php echo substr($arscript[21],6,8); ?>"> kbit/s<br>



    <name="input" action="html_form_action.php" method="get">
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fseek function  http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php , you can seek to the desired position and then write to the file, like below

```
<?php
  $file = fopen($filename, "c");
  fseek($file, -3, SEEK_END);
  fwrite($file, "whatever you want to write");
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but this doesnt help me that much, I need the text that I write in the input boxes to be saved in the exact same place where I got the last known variable from.